# python sqlalchemy - can't get cascade delete to work - in mssql manager

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, cascade

I have this code, thats been mostly taken from the sqlalchemy site

```
class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'order'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('tri_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String(1024), nullable=False)
    items = relationship("Item", cascade="save-update, delete-orphan, merge, delete", backref="parent")

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('tri_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String(1024), nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('order.id'))
```

I want deletes to Order to cascade down and delete its items as well. In code:

```
# test insert/delete - save data to mssql server
i1 = Item(text="item one")
i2 = Item(text="item two")
o = Order(text="one", items=[i1, i2])
session.add(o)
session.commit()

session.delete(o) # delete it
# tests to make sure items/order gone ....
session.commit()
```

This works ok.

BUT if I try and delete an Order in MS SQL management studio. i.e.

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[order] WHERE id = 1
```

I get the error
"the DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint FK__item__parent_id_1D00044F" The conflict error blah blah....

I guess theres something missing on the relationship definitions but I can't see it.

Any help/thoughts?

ta.

Comment: Try to add `CASCADE` at the end of your SQL request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)

    user = relationship("User", backref=backref('comments', cascade="all,delete", order_by=id))
```

This kind of setup works for me, my `User` class doesn't have any special fields except for primary key.
So basically, this works as intended, when I delete the user - his comments are gone as well.
It doesn't have to be deletion through `SQLAlchemy` either, this code creates an appropriate table structure, that even if you delete user manually (sql query) - cascade deletion will still work.

Comment: yup that fixes it. I was missing the ForeignKey(.. ondelete='CASCADE'). many thanks.